# Using library(VennDiagram) to save an .EPS file?

Tags: r, eps, venn-diagram

I use the following code to generate an EPS

```
venn.plot = draw.triple.venn( area1=leftLen, area2=rightLen, area3=midLen, n12=(left_rightLen+allIntersectLen), n23=(right_midLen+allIntersectLen), n13=(left_midLen+allIntersectLen), n123=allIntersectLen, category = c("Left Leaning", "Right Leaning", "Central"), lty="blank", fill = c("blue", "red", "purple") )
```

How can I save this as an EPS file?  I tried doing

```
setEPS()
postscript( filePathForEpsFile )
plot( venn.plot )
```

And I get an error.  How am I supposed to save this as an EPS file?

Answer (score 0):

I may be off with this answer, since you do not provide a reproducible example; at least, your venn.plot code gives me this:

```
Error in draw.triple.venn(area1 = leftLen, area2 = rightLen, area3 = midLen,  : 
  object 'leftLen' not found
```

nor do you provide us the error that you get.

However, looking at how you call your venn.plot, I'm thinking that might be the issue. If you look at the VennDiagram [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf) you can see that you do not need to (or perhaps shouldn't?) use plot() to plot your diagram. They use grid.draw().

So, trying this out on one of the simple examples in their manual:

```
library(VennDiagram)
venn.plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(100, 70, 30, c("First", "Second"))
plot(venn.plot)
```

This code gives me the following error.

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Is that the error that you were talking about?

The following code however

```
grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

nicely draws your venn diagram.
[image: ExampleVenn]

Upon which they often wipe the slate with

```
grid.newpage()
```

to avoid plotting venn on top of venn.

Saving the venn diagram as an EPS then simply boils down to this:

```
setEPS()
postscript(file = "ExampleVenn.EPS", fonts = "serif")
grid.draw(venn.plot)
dev.off()
```

I added fonts = "serif" to the postscript call to avoid an error saying

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  family 'serif' not included in postscript() device
```

When you get this error the labels in your diagram are not saved to the EPS file.
I hope this helps solving your issue.